# Google Drive API starred files from others

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to add files to my favorites. Its work with my own files but not with others. (No permission 403). I work with the .net API v2 in vb.net

```
 Dim newfile As New Data.File()
 newfile.Labels = New Data.File.LabelsData
 newfile.Labels.Starred = True
 Dim request As FilesResource.UpdateRequest = service.Files.Update(newfile, file.Id)
 request.Execute()
```

Same result with patch.

When I test it here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#try-it it works perfect.

Is there any way to use the .net API?